# JQuery hiding parent element if div has no content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got code like this.. I need to hide the parent div if div class=content has no content in it.
can anyone please tell me how i can do this.
It seems simple, googled about 2-3 hours,but I could not solve this..

```
      <div id="row-custom_57" class="section custom_57-section">
        <div class="label">
            Designation
        </div>
         <div class="content">

         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="row-birth_date" class="section birth_date-section">
        <div class="label">
            Date of birth
        </div>
         <div class="content">

         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="row-birth_date" class="section birth_date-section">
        <div class="label">
            Date of birth
        </div>
         <div class="content">

         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

#

I tried something like this. but no luck. its not entering into if condition.. can anyone please tell me how to do this.

```
                $('.content').each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).text());
                    //console.log($(this).html());
                    if($(this).html() === null)
                    {
                        console.log('innnnn' + $(this).html);
                        //$(this).hide();
                        //$(this).parent().hide();
                        //$(this).parent().parent().hide();
                    }
                    else{
                            //console.log($(this).html());
                    }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `console.log('innnnn' + $(this).html);` <<--- missing `()`? is it returning `null`??

Comment: its not entering into if.. I tried using if($(this).html() == ''){// do something } as well but it did not work either.

Comment: Use .is(':empty') to find out if element is empty.

Comment: [Is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/jgz63ch0/)

Comment: Why can't people create jsfiddle and post it here to their question?  why? 1st world problems...

Comment: @Rumplin is(':empty') regards whitespace as content, this may be undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the content actually null or is it an empty string?

What happens if you try this:

```
if($(this).html().match(/^\s*$/))
{
    console.log('innnnn' + $(this).html);
}
```

Comment: thank you. its working fine. thanks alot, saved my time.thanks everyone for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it:

```
$('.content').each(function(){
    if($(this).html()==''){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

the value returned from `$(this).html()` is a string, so it will never be `null`, it'll just be `''` (empty)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's prefer to check this way:

```
$(this).text()
```

Because this return only text excluding html tags.